App Not Compatible with Latest Version Despite Using Latest Flutter Version
I'm encountering an issue where my Flutter app is not compatible with the latest version, even though I am using the latest Flutter SDK. Here are the details of my setup and the problem:
Setup:
Flutter version: 3.22.0
compileSdkVersion: 34
minSdkVersion: 21
targetSdkVersion: 34
AND majorly facing this issue into 2 devices which is
Pixel 8 pro (Android version 14)
Samsung A51 (Android version 13)

Flutter version: 3.22.0
compileSdkVersion: 34
minSdkVersion: 21
targetSdkVersion: 34
I want to install the app on all devices with all Android versions

Does this answer your question? "your device isn't compatible with this version"

Its not a Flutter SDK issue.
it might be issue with your Manifest or build.gradle(app lavel) file.

Declared specific Target Sdk Version.
Min sdk version.
Already Fix some specific size in manifest file

So, You have to keep in mind that you have to reach maximum devices for your target, you have to Opt out some of the features and Permissions.
Hope this gives you idea.

I have set the compileSdkVersion to 34, minSdkVersion to 21, and targetSdkVersion to 34 in the build.gradle file. I have also verified that the manifest file is correct.
However, when I tested the app on a Oneplus 9 device running Android version 14, the app installed successfully. This indicates that the issue may not be related to the Android version, so we need to investigate something else

check if you have something like this in your manifest.

it may be creating issue

No, nothing like this,
i'm encountering this issue, and three of my other clients are experiencing the same problem. It appears to be a problem affecting all apps on a specific device where the app is not installed
